# Using webrtc for android，how to save a image in the video call?

Tags: android, webrtc, save-image

I don't know how to get the video frame , so I can't save the image.

Give me some tips. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Question - Do you want to capture videoframe of the videoview or the whole screen?

Comment: Both them can solve  my quetion! Neji, could you share some solutions with me?

Comment: Can you use TextureView instead of VideoView for showing video?

Comment: Thanks ! But it can't be allowed use TextureView.Because webrtc use the GLSurfaceView to rendering the mediastream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As canvas and rest of the facilities are unavailable in Android we can dodge this situation by taking screenshots and introducing animation in our app's UI. screenshot image can be stored at configured location and resused it later for exchanging it to other party

Edit: One can take reference from AppRTC to capture surfaceview()

https://codereview.webrtc.org/1257043004/

GLSurfaceView ()  should not work as webrtc library has the hold of camera and screen. One has to build extended class to get Videorenderer and get the snap of frame , Once done one can display the frame using customized api displayFrame() mentioned by  cferran in opentok android examples.

You can also use OpenTok library but that is chargeable when compared to webRTC.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! Could you share  any specific ways to solve this ? Now I use the app's UI "GLSurfaceView",but it makes no sense. I have tried many ways but failed.

Comment: Thanks for your patience once again! The OpenTok library may be a good solution. But our company want to reduce the output. I hava found another solution! Firstly  through webrtc ,I can get the I420frame in the method 'RenderFrame'. Then I convert the I420frame to YuvImage. Finally,I use the YuvImage's method 'compressToJpeg' to convert it to jpeg image.

Comment: Liked your approach, requesting to confirm the quality and size of image saved by this method once done.

Comment: I find that the image has a little gray. Now I am finding the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using a third party library here is an example on how to implement this use case: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Live-Photo-Capture

If you prefer to use directly WebRTC, here you can find generic information about how to build WebRTC on Android: https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/